# Tesseract cannot find eng.traineddata

Tags: python-3.x, ocr, tesseract

I have python program which uses tesseract ocr engine. At first it worked fine. However I uninstall tesseract and reinstall it this time it does not work.

It gives

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR/eng.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX
```

I did not change anything, but it does not work.

I add TESSDATA_PREFIX to the path.

But when I move eng.traineddata from tesstada to tesseract-ocr file it worked. I have another computer and also it has same program and it works well. However eng.traineddata is in tessdata folder.

Why is the one program gives an error, another is not ?

## EDIT

1) 'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR/eng.traineddata' does not exist in two computers. However one of them is working but the other is not working. Therefore As I stated in the question, I move eng.traineddata from tessdata to Tesseract-OCR folder and then it is worked. But here is the question why one of it is working and the other is not working ? Because other program does not have eng.traineddata in the Tesseract-OCR folder.

2) I downloaded the windows executable of tesseract from mannheim uni library. So file is not corrupted.

3)I am using Tesseract 3.05

4) I have created TESSDATA_PREFIX env variable.

5) I downloaded the windows executable of tesseract from mannheim uni library.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

1. Does 'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR/eng.traineddata' exists?
2. Did you check if file is not corrupted (e.g. you downloaded it correctly)
3. From which (tessdata repository) source you downloaded it?
4. Adding `TESSDATA_PREFIX` to paths is useless: you have to setup env variable `TESSDATA_PREFIX`.
5. Provide full code how you setup and run pytesseract. Showing only (part of) error message does not help.

Comment: If you use mannheim installer it does not mean that files can not be corrupted. But what you wrote indicates that you set up TESSDATA_PREFIX  wrong way (either during installation or later). I guess it points to  'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR', but it should be  'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata'. AFAIK installer set it correctly if you do not change it.

Comment: 'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata this does not work.